# Android auto enabled app doesn't push notifications to car device

Tags: android, android-auto

I made an app for android auto devices. I tested it using the Android auto `Messaging Simulator`. All the notifications that I sent using my mobile app, are showing on the simulator. And then I tried with a real car device. When I'm sending notifications using mobile app to the real car device, It's not showing any notification. Any one can help me on this? What is the issue?

I'm using the `Pioneer AVIC-7100NEX` car device.

Comment: Android Auto devices do not allow the side loading of applications. You'll need to upload it to the playstore and then it will work. If it works on the simulator it'll work on the real device once you upload.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'll try it and let you know.